# No green light on Mid 2011 13" MBA, continues to charge. Why is it not on? Could this be an issue with the SMC?

Tags: power-management, magsafe

My magsafe charger has no green light, but my mac is charging. [image: No green light]

[image: Mac charging still]

I have tried a SMC reset and still, no green light.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The light should be orange while charging, right. Did you try a different charger / different Mac?

Comment: the charger works on all other computers, what i am asking is, why is my charger neither green or orange, I am aware that this could be an issue with the SMC, why cant you understand what I am asking?

Comment: because there is no question ;)

Comment: just poking in the dark here: did you try cleaning the connections and does the issue persist when you connect the Magsafe the other way around?

Comment: oh and what happens when the battery is full?

Comment: sometimes it will come on, right now typing this it came on, but it is green, my percentage is 97%, I thought it is orange until fully charged.

Comment: For all intensive purposes, 97% **is** fully charged. About the no show of light, how'd you do the SMC reset? My [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256507/205310) about how to do a SMC reset may help.

Comment: According to Apple's website.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following to reset the charging options:

- Shut down your Mac.
- Unplug the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter from your computer.
- Using the built-in keyboard, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds.
- Release all keys.
- Reconnect the power adapter.
- Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.